# Excel VBA Cells.Find fails unless I use Application.Wait. Why?

Tags: excel, vba, replace

I'm working on a VBA macro, and I came across some pretty strange behavior.

It works fine with `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`, and even just fine when screen updating is off and using the VBA debugger to step through the macro.

Just running the macro with screen updating off, unfortunately, causes the `Find` function to fail in the following code:

```
Application.StatusBar = "Extracting data and updating tables..."
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Workbooks.Open FileName:=Save_folder & "new_data.xls"
Workbooks("new_data.xls").Sheets("data").Range("B9:B39").Copy

Dim tempdate As Date, startCell As Range

tempdate = DateAdd("d", -1, Now)
tempdate = DateSerial(Year(tempdate), Month(tempdate), 1) 'Start of the month
Dim strdate As String
strdate = Format(tempdate, "Short Date")

Set startCell = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw Data").Cells.Find(What:=CDate(strdate), After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw Data").Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas _
 , LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

If startCell Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Couldn't find a date equal to the start of yesterday's month."
    Exit Sub
Else
    startCell.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=False
End If
```

Adding this short snippet above the call to `Cells.Find` solves the problem:

```
'Wait one second, to appease the Excel object creation gods
Application.StatusBar = "Wait one second..."
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
Application.StatusBar = "Pasting values..."
```

Throwing up a `MsgBox` or prompt, etc. also allows the `Find` to succeed.

My question is, why do I have to wait?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am unable to produce this behavior. See screenshot

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim tempdate As Date, startCell As Range
    Dim strdate As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    tempdate = DateAdd("d", -1, Now)
    tempdate = DateSerial(Year(tempdate), Month(tempdate), 1) 'Start of the month

    strdate = Format(tempdate, "Short Date")

    Set startCell = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw Data").Cells.Find(What:=CDate(strdate), LookIn:=xlFormulas _
     , LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

    If startCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Couldn't find a date equal to the start of yesterday's month."
    Else
        MsgBox "Found"
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

**UPDATE**:

If there are lot of things happening in your code then use `DoEvents` so that the code passes control to the operating system so that the operating system can process other events.

Comment: +1 for DoEvents - a complex spreadsheet can take more than 1 second to recalculate

Answer (score 0):

I came across this thread while trying to solve the same issue, and I was able to get around the DoEvents trick by simply activating the worksheet before running any of the .Find functions.

The only thing that rhymes between your code and mine is that they both use the .Find function. Perhaps that is what clogs up the operating system.